# At leetcode, using Python3, how come this function be faster than the two simple others?

Tags: python, time-complexity

The exercise is at this [Link](https://leetcode.com/problems/length-of-last-word/description/).

How can a solution with ".split()" be faster than any solution running only a while counting the last word size? Like:

```
class Solution:
    def lengthOfLastWord(self, s: str) -> int:
        for word in s.split(' ')[::-1]:
            if word != '':
                return len(word)
```

Faster than:

```
class Solution:
    def lengthOfLastWord(self, s: str) -> int:
        firstLetter = len(s) -1
        for i in range(firstLetter, -1, -1):
            if s[i] != ' ':
                firstLetter = i
                break
        for i in range(firstLetter, -1, -1):
            if s[i] == ' ':
                return firstLetter - i
        return firstLetter+1
```

or

```
class Solution:
    def lengthOfLastWord(self, s: str) -> int:
        # trim the trailing spaces
        p = len(s) - 1
        while p >= 0 and s[p] == ' ':
            p -= 1

        # compute the length of last word
        length = 0
        while p >= 0 and s[p] != ' ':
            p -= 1
            length += 1
        return length
```

Comment: `str.split` is implemented in C;  it runs much faster than the equivalent pure Python code.

Comment: Btw, `reversed(s.split())` should be even faster

Comment: This will probably be even faster: `return len(s.split()[-1])`

Comment: Time complexity is useful for determining how an algorithm's time changes as the input grows. But it won't tell you which algorithm is faster with the same input.

Comment: I know that Python has these peculiarities. The question raises an interesting way to think when working with Python, not only the algorithm, but the entire way that the solution is executed.